# PHP proc_open unable to handle path with spaces?

Tags: php, php-7

I am trying to use PHING to check out a git repository as part of a build process. PHING uses pear/versioncontrol_git to handle git tasks. My path to git is `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`.

Two commands are run using this path, `<gitpath> --version` and `<gitpath> clone -q -repo=...`

`<gitpath> --version` works fine. `<gitpath> clone...`  gives an error that `C:\Program` is not a valid path. I am confused why this would be a problem when the exact same code can execute the `--version` command with no error.

What appears to be happening is that the quotes are getting stripped off, but only sometimes.

This is the offending code:

```
public function execute($arguments = array(), $options = array())
{
    $command = $this->createCommandString($arguments, $options);

    $descriptorspec = array(
        1 => array('pipe', 'w'),
        2 => array('pipe', 'w'),
    );
    $pipes = array();
    $resource = proc_open($command, $descriptorspec, $pipes, realpath($this->git->getDirectory()));

    $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    foreach ($pipes as $pipe) {
        fclose($pipe);
    }

    $status = trim(proc_close($resource));
    if ($status) {
        $message = "Some errors in executing git command . $command\n\n"
                 . "Output:\n"
                 . $stdout."\n"
                 . "Error:\n"
                 . $stderr;
        var_dump($message);
        throw new VersionControl_Git_Exception($message);
    } else {
        var_dump('No errors in ' . $command);
    }

    return $this->stripEscapeSequence($stdout);
}
```

And this is the output of two calls to the code:

```
C:\PHP Projects\Build\vendor\pear\versioncontrol_git\VersionControl\Git\Util\Command.php:240:
string(61) "No errors in "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\git.exe" --version"
C:\PHP Projects\Build\vendor\pear\versioncontrol_git\VersionControl\Git\Util\Command.php:237:
string(306) "Some errors in executing git command . "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\git.exe" clone -q --branch="master" "--REDACTED--" "C:\PHP Projects\Build\build"

Output:

Error:
'C:\\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Hi, did you found a solution to this issue? I'm facing the same problem currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with the --version but the problem is with the command you are executing to run **git clone** or **git checkout**.

You can't run **git clone** command or **git checkout** command with **git.exe**

while when you can run **--version** command with **git.exe** which is **"C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe" --version**

So the conclusion is you have to set command while running git clone or git checkout your path should be

**"C:/Program Files/Git/bin>" git clone**
or
**"C:/Program Files/Git/bin>" git checkout**

Let me know if you still have an issue with that.

Thank you.